# Thinking process in html and css, size structures?

Tags: html, css, layout, architecture

I am trying to frame my question. I want to know how to decide the margins and padding values in designing CSS. Is there any specific rule that governs these values, or is it random that looks good to eyes?

How to break page into rows and columns? Should we break page vertically into columns first or horizontally (in rows)?

My question is regarding the HTML architecture. Are there any specific guidelines for HTML architecture?

Answer (score 1):

For margin and padding, my general goto guide
- taken from chakra ui

```
  "0": "0",
  "1": "0.25rem",
  "2": "0.5rem",
  "3": "0.75rem",
  "4": "1rem",
  "5": "1.25rem",
  "6": "1.5rem",
  "8": "2rem",
  "10": "2.5rem",
  "12": "3rem",
  "16": "4rem",
  "20": "5rem",
  "24": "6rem",
  "32": "8rem",
  "40": "10rem",
  "48": "12rem",
  "56": "14rem",
  "64": "16rem"
```

For structuring, start from top to bottom and make vertical sections, make rows

```html
<body>
  <header></header>

  <section class="banner-section"></section>

  <section class="work-section"></section>

  <section class="contact-section"></section>

  <footer></footer>
</body>;
```

Now that I have decided the overall structure, its time to go ahead and tackle inside the sections

```html
<header>
  <div class="important-msg">
    <p>Share this page with everyone</p>
  </div>
  <nav>
    <img src="logo.png" width="">Logo</h1>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="home">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="about">About</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="contact">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Inside the header I created 2 rows  and ,
and inside `<div>`, I inserted message with a `<p>` tag.

And inside the nav, there are 2 elements `<img>` and `<ul>`, now I need to arrange them in columns so that they remain in a single row.
Naturally that means `<li>` and `<a>` inside of `<ul>` have to be arranged inline.

This is how I apporach. Start with rows and dive in to make rows and then if the elements are side by side, make columns.